# Значение слова "озвучить"

Tags: значение-слов

Сейчас очень часто по телевидению от комментаторов и даже дикторов можно услышать фразы типа "Иванов озвучил своё предложение" или "Это было озвучено на заседании....".Правильно ли применение "озвучить", очень режет слух.

Comment: И  мне  не  нравится,  действительно  режет  слух.

Answer (score 4):

"Иванов озвучил своё предложение" - сначала подумал над предложением, а потом его  озвучил - сделал звуковым, слышным для всех - всё нормально.

"Это было озвучено на заседании...." - было только на бумаге, а на заседании озвучено; всё в порядке со смыслом, мне слух не режет, особенно в газетном варианте, в хронике, в отчёте, где речь передаёт канцелярские обороты чиновников. В простом бытовом разговоре действительно режет слух, это канцеляризм, книжный стиль, а в протоколе и газетной хронике вполне приемлемо.

В Викисловаре эти значения слова (огласить, объявить, представить, наполнить звуками)  даны как разговорные
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C, но лет 5-6 эти значения используются в СМИ, на радио и т.д., а если они "пришлись ко двору", их понимают, думаю, они войдут и в общее употребление, разговорные слова иногда становятся нормой. Я вот восприняла как канцелярит (в отчётах), а подумать - просто появилось новое значение у старого слова. Вот здесь ещё рассуждения о разговорности значения: http://www.rg.ru/2012/02/09/ozvuchit.html: 
http://gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_152

Comment: Почему-то раньше это не было канцеляризмом,тем более "книжным" стилем извините, я этого не слышала.

Comment: "огласить" никак не может быть разговорным, поскольку известно с момента ***оглашения*** царских указов.

Comment: я говорю не о слове "огласить", а об этом значении у слова "озвучить".

Answer (score 3):

> Почему-то раньше это не было канцеляризмом,тем более "книжным" стилем извините, я этого не слышала, а не лучше ли бы сказать "Иванов предложил..."

"Предложил" - это немного другое значение. Вернее было бы "огласил". Сейчас это "огласил" выходит из употребления, возможно поэтому "озвучил" и появляется где надо и не надо.

Я не буду дискутировать на тему "канцеляризм" ли это, ибо все весьма условно, но канцелярит в каком-то смысле тоже живой язык - в нем появляются и исчезают новые обороты.

По сути. Мне - "озвучить" резало всегда и режет сейчас слух почти везде. Кроме использования по прямому назначению: озвучивание ("озвучка") фильмов.

Answer (score 1):

Старое советское слово *озвучить* в словаре Ушакова :

> **ОЗВУЧИТЬ** 
> озвучу, озвучишь, сов. (к озвучивать), что (кино нов.). Сделать звуковым (кинофильм). Озвучить фильм. Озвучить картину. ? Приспособить для демонстрации звуковых кинофильмов. Озвучить кинотеатр.

Озвучка советских кинофильмов плавно перешла в озвучку российских административных новшеств, ибо главные актеры сегодня - это чиновники и политики. Они каждый день тусуются в масс-медиа и озвучивают свои роли. Практически для населения они являются говорящими головами, как раньше ими были дикторы.

Вот предтеча современного словоупотребления :

> Игорь Рувинский. Требуется переводчик с... электротехнического // «Техника - молодежи», **1974** Но как быть с техническими документами, миллиарды которых ежегодно вращаются в сфере производства и ― **если бы их озвучить** ― напоминают все тот же разноязыкий гвалт, характерный для городка вавилонских строителей?

*Птички проснулись и озвучили новый день, каждая на свой особый лад*.